# NodeJS adding numbers from mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this basic code in express

```
var currpoints = user.points;
var addedpoints = req.body.points;
var newpoints = currpoints+addedpoints;

user.points = newpoints;
```

If `currentpoints = 10` and `addedpoints = 100` then its returning 10100 for the `var newpoints`.

How can I alter this so it adds 10 + 100 to 110?

Comment: could it be that JS thinks that these are strings?

Comment: Try playing with numbers as strings in Chrome console: ```10 + '100' =>
"10100";
'10' + 100 => "10100";
'10' + '100' => "10100";
parseInt('10', 10) + parseInt('100', 10)
110```
JavaScript will "coerce" numbers to strings if one param is string.

The second param to parseInt is base (some old versions of JS had a behavior of converting "010" as octal number to decimal 8, for example, so you explicitly set the base to 10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like JavaScript is treating the values as strings.

You could do either:

```
var currpoints = parseInt(user.points, 10);
var addedpoints = parseInt(req.body.points, 10);
var newpoints = currpoints + addedpoints;
```

Or

```
var currpoints = user.points;
var addedpoints = req.body.points;
var newpoints = parseInt(currpoints, 10) + parseInt(addedpoints, 10);
```

That should then return the correct number instead of concatenating the strings together.